# How can i put alert messages if this scripts fails or success

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
    $.post("countest.php",
    {loader:1},function(data){
        $("#inc").html(data)
    });
},5000);
```

});

I am a newbie in this PL ,this scripts work just like i want but i think there is something missing thanks for the help in advance:)

Comment: Please add a bit more context to the question. The specific use of the script and the what the parameters correspond to, etc. Doing so will help other members to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fail` callback to perform some specific action when request fails

```
$.post("countest.php",{loader:1},function(data){
    $("#inc").html(data)
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```